# Length method in java , when used on input string does not produce the expected result

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

My initial code that does not produce the desired result:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Strings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter your word: ");
       String word1 = sc.next();
       System.out.println(word1.length());
       sc.close();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 tk@localhost:~$ java Strings
                 Enter your word: 
                 avada kedavra
                 5
```

Which is not the length of my string.
But when I try this(without the user input) :

```
class Strings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = new String("avada kedavra");
        System.out.println(str.length());
    }
}
```

Output :

```
 tk@localhost:~$ java Strings  
                 13
```

It works!
So , why doesn't it work when I take input from the user? What am I missing?

Comment: The next word is avada.

Comment: Use `sc.nextLine()`

Comment: Thanks. That worked!

Comment: The java scanner's `next()` method has whitespaces as delimiters. That means whenever it finds one, the string you're reading ends there. Do as Eran said and use `nextLine()` if everything is in one line (be careful, if there are new lines you'll have to use `nextLine()` as many times as lines you have, or you'll have the same problem)

Comment: And just for the record: although your question was closed as dup - dont forget about accepting one of the answers at some point. I find your question is well written, and "good enough" to stay.

Comment: Down-voted as the answer can easily be found by either reading the javadoc for `Scanner` or debugging.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, [`sc.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) finds and returns the next complete *token*. By default, a token is a *word*, something separated with spaces or newline (`\p{javaWhitespace}+`).

So in your first example, `word1 = "avada"`, with length 5.

Use `sc.nextLine()` to get the complete line.

Comment: To be complete, it use the [`delimiter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#delimiter()), `\p{javaWhitespace}+` by default. This can be changed to match another [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) if we don't want to read the full line.

Comment: @GhostCat There are many when you just search for `java scanner read whole line` :).

Comment: @Tom ... there is a reason why you have 5000 more votes than me ;-) ... and honestly: I search for `java scanner next` and maybe with `token`.

Comment: @GhostCat Nah, that's too specific, a more general search yields better results. Also never use the internal search engine, it sucks ( :'( ). Use Google or your favorite external search engine and add `site:stackoverflow.com` if the search result contains too many other sites. Anyway, I appreciate it that you've searched for a dupe :).

Comment: @Tom I know. I hate the internal search. I have "favorited" my top three (NPE, array out of bounds, string out of bounds) so that I can close-dup those quicker ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In short: [RTFM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())

A bit longer for the click-lazy: Scanner returns the "next token" when calling `next` Tokens are calculated by taking a pattern, which is "all whitespaces" by default. So your call of next returns the next word and not the complete line as you intended.

Set a fitting pattern when instantiating `Scanner` or call `nextLine` instead.

Comment: I don't see the difference with the other answer...

Comment: @Derlin Overlap in time. When I started writing, there was no answer, I simply needed longer because I had to get the link to the Javadoc

Comment: I understand  ^^